# Backup my EFI boot entry for easy restore

Tags: boot, backup, uefi, restore

Giving that Windows 10 would most likely wipe my Linux EFI boot entry, See the comment after the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/667659/374303):

> Windows 10 will usually "self-heal" its firmware boot entry if you manage to get Windows booting even once. In the process, if there is no existing Windows boot entry in the firmware (i.e. in the `efibootmgr` list), it will usually usurp `Boot0000` for itself, regardless of whether or not it is already in use.

I'd like to backup my EFI boot entry before so that I can then easily restore it even Windows 10 wipes it.

Seems there is no existing tools that can do it, though https://github.com/rhboot/efibootmgr/issues/10 mentioned the `efivar` utility, with somewhat manual process. However, I cannot find any further info into that direction.

Hence the question. Or, if I have a EFI boot entry like this:

```
Boot0000* debian        HD(13,GPT,007a058a-8e5e-45df-8d97-6575b66b5355,0x1afa9000,0x113000)/File(\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi)
```

How to recreate it next time?

Comment: Windows will not touch your EFI boot entry, it will just make its own entry the first in the list.

Comment: Indeed @MichaelHampton, it turned out to be exactly so. thx.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's easy enough to recreate a boot entry from scratch once you know how... and have the `efibootmgr` tool at hand, of course.

> `Boot0000* debian        HD(13,GPT,007a058a-8e5e-45df-8d97-6575b66b5355,0x1afa9000,0x113000)/File(\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi)`

The `007a058a-8e5e-45df-8d97-6575b66b5355` is the PARTUUID of the ESP partition the `\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi` is located in. (The `13` *may* be a partition number, but according to the specification, the PARTUUID is the primary identifier.)

The `efibootmgr` command just needs to know the disk: it will find the ESP partition on that disk, and its PARTUUID, automatically on its own, assuming there is only one ESP per disk. So, let's assume that this PARTUUID belongs to your `/dev/sda13` partition (use `blkid` or `lsblk -o +partuuid` to check).

To recreate the boot entry (or to make an extra copy of it right now):

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -L debian -l \\EFI\\debian\\grubx64.efi
```

Backslashes are doubled because backslash is a special escape character for the shell.

This command will automatically find the ESP partition on `/dev/sda` and its PARTUUID, and will build the boot entry for you.

`efibootmgr` will automatically pick the first free `BootNNNN` number for the boot entry, and will also automatically add it as the first entry in the `BootOrder`. So if `Boot0000` already exists, this would create `Boot0001` and set `BootOrder` to `0001,0000` if it previously was just `0000`.

This would be an effective backup of your current boot entries:

```
(lsblk -o +partuuid; efibootmgr -v) > boot-entry-repair-kit.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than back up your firmware efi boot entry, just have the tools on hand to easily recover it.

Usually windows doesn't delete your linux entry, but it may prioritize itself first.  Modern firmwares will let you pull up a boot menu, which should list devices and all the EFI entries that have been installed.  You should be able to select the linux entry from there, and possibly re-run the grub installer or efibootmgr to reorder the entries if you want to.

If you have an older firmware that doesn't support multiple entries, you should be able to go into the settings and edit the current entry and record what is there, and then re-enter it manually later if windows does erase it.

All that failing, you can install an EFI selector like refind on a usb stick and use it to search your EFI ESP partition for bootable operating systems and select linux from there, and then reinstall grub as above.

If linux in the EFI partition itself is damaged, refind sometimes can reach directly into the linux partition and boot the kernel directly.

An alternative to that would be to boot linux install media in recovery mode and have it repair the EFI entry.